# arm-none-eabi-gcc not inferring floating point multiply-accumulate from code

Tags: gcc, arm, compiler-optimization, cortex-m

The ARM fpv5 instruction set supports double precision floating point operations, including single cycle multiply accumulate instructions (VMLA/VMLS) as detailed in their ISA documentation.

Unfortunately, I can't get my code to use this instruction from within any C application.

Here is a simple example:

```
float64_t a=0, b=0, c=0;

while(1)
{
        b += 1.643;
        c += 3.901;
        a += b * c; // multiply accumulate???

        do_stuff(a) // use the MAC result

}
```

The code above generates the following assembly for (what I believe should be) a MAC operation

```
170               a += b * c;
00000efe:   vldr    d6, [r7, #64]   ; 0x40
00000f02:   vldr    d7, [r7, #56]   ; 0x38
00000f06:   vmul.f64        d7, d6, d7
00000f0a:   vldr    d6, [r7, #72]   ; 0x48
00000f0e:   vadd.f64        d7, d6, d7
00000f12:   vstr    d7, [r7, #72]   ; 0x48
```

As you can see, it does the multiply and the addition step separately. **Is there a good reason why the compiler cant use the `VMLA.f64` instruction here?**

- Target: ARM Cortex M7 (NXP iMXRT1051)
- Toolchain: arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 8-2018-q4-major) 8.2.1 20181213 (release) [gcc-8-branch revision 267074]

Comment: Not very knowledgeable on this, but what makes sense logically is that it's a lot harder to ensure that a MAC is what you want here. It's likely much safer, and not very much more costly, to just do the multiply and then add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was the optimization level. When set to -O3 the instructions changed to properly use the MAC.

I thought that taking advantage of hardware acceleration (e.g. FPU) wouldn't be dependent on the optimization level since its essentially "free", but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Beware that you may need to use -ffast-math to get fused instructions like multiply-accumulate due to ever so slight differences in precision.